# x86 assembly string array pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm stuck at the part when I finish multiplied the first number by second number, and the third number the pointer in num[] will change to 90 in ASCII code

For example, if I enter '345' as a string, I separate it to several char '3', '4', '5' ,and I multiples 3 by 10 and plus 4, then ebx will be 34 and jump back to L5 while ptr[edx] should be point at '5', but it shows point at the number '42' in the end, please let me know where the problem is, tks.
Here is my code:

```
    L3:
    movzx ebx,byte ptr[edx]
    sub ebx,48                      ;ASCII -48
    inc edx                         ;char to next

    L5:
    cmp byte ptr[edx],' '
    jne mmul

    mmul:
    movzx eax,byte ptr[edx]         ;turn int
    mov next,eax
    sub next,48
    mov eax,ebx                     ;
    mov cx,10
    mul cx
    mov ebx,eax                     ;ebx*10
    add ebx,next                    ;
    inc edx                         ;
    jmp L5
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow (SO) :) If I understand correctly, you are asking two separate questions here. One of the ideas of SO is that, if you have multiple questions, then you also post multiple questions and don't merge them into one as you'd do in a forum, for example.

Comment: In addition I'd ask you to narrow down your code a bit more. It's great to provide a large enough code snippet to get some context, but it's also important to tell us which section of the code you think is the problem, which behaviour from your code you are expecting and what it is that you're actually seeing. This will make it much easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: thank u for your advice, I'll correct it late :))

Comment: `mul cx` doesn't do EAX*=10, it leaves the upper 2 bytes of EAX unmodified.  Use `imul ebx, 10` like a normal person; this isn't 16-bit 8086 code where you can't assume the immediate and reg,reg versions of imul.  See [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19309749) if you just want working code for unsigned integers.  (Use MASM `byte ptr` instead of NASM `byte`)

Comment: Also, why would you store/reload to `next` inside the loop?  Use registers; that's what they're for.

Comment: uh, actually, I used them for store the pointer of array and the sizeof, TA told me that I shouldn't use other registers (not include eax,ebx,ecx,edx) because they have other important use. Isn't it correct?